# remotely running find -exec options

Tags: unix, bash, cygwin, command-line-interface

I'm trying to setup a bash process for deploying my django project onto a linux server.

Through cygwin, I'm running a script that is calling scp to copy my files over. Is there a similar command to delete *.pyc files. As of now, I've only been able to accomplish this locally after using ssh with:

```
find . -name "*.pyc" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

I'm looking for some kind of command to call remotely that would be equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ssh.  The format of ssh is

> ssh user@host command

so something like

> ssh user@host 'find . -name "*.pyc" -exec rm -rf {} \;'

You should probably use absolute paths for the remote server so you know exactly where you are deleting files.  Test it out with

> ssh user@host 'find . -name "*.pyc" -print'

Answer (score 1):

you can sync your local to remote with rsync over ssh and have the
Delete option